# Sharepoint 2k7 - Custom WebPart not loading

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

First off i am a big fat NOOB in regards to Sharepoint 2007 webpart development but i am working at it.

Now for the real problem, so i develop this webpart and follow the 'Loose' advise from various sites on how to setup the features.xml, .xml, manifest.xml, solution.ddf and solution.build files.  Basically, i have a all-in-one solution where i build the webpart and then in post-build event compile all the source files into the WSP deployment package.

Problem i am having is that I can add the solution to the sharepoint site but when i go to Deploy it through CA-Operations-Solution management i get this great error:

> ### Error as reported from Sharepoint
>
> Failed to instantiate file "ChartPartWP.webpart" from module "ChartPartWP": Source path "ChartPartWP\ChartPartWP.webpart" not found.

When i looked at the file-system the folder ChartPart is present in TEMPLATE\FEATURES with the ChartPartWP.webpart and other support files.

What is not happening that i need to resolve.

Edit: 10/24/2011 @ 11:36PM

### Solution.ddf

```
.OPTION EXPLICIT
.Set CabinetNameTemplate=ChartPartWP.wsp
.Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=CDROM
.Set DiskDirectory1=Package
.Set CompressionType=MSZIP
.Set UniqueFiles="ON"
.Set Cabinet=On
.Set SourceDir="\\<fileserver>\common share\Software_Development\MPT\Sharepoint2007\ChartPart\"

Manifest.xml manifest.xml

; binary
bin\release\TCBOE.ChartPart.dll TCBOE.ChartPart.dll

; feature files
TEMPLATE\FEATURES\ChartPartWP\ChartPartWP.xml ChartPartWP\ChartPartWP.xml
TEMPLATE\FEATURES\ChartPartWP\feature.xml ChartPartWP\Feature.xml

; web part files
TEMPLATE\FEATURES\ChartPartWP\ChartPartWP.webpart ChartPartWP\ChartPartWP.webpart
TEMPLATE\FEATURES\ChartPartWP\LockedChartPartWP.webpart ChartPartWP\LockedChartPartWP.webpart
```

### manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
 SolutionId="{0C32EA7F-78C2-4814-A4C9-88256E49E371}">
  <FeatureManifests>
    <FeatureManifest Location="ChartPartWP\feature.xml" />
  </FeatureManifests>
  <Assemblies>
    <Assembly Location="TCBOE.ChartPart.dll"
              DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
  </Assemblies>
</Solution>
```

### ChartPartWP.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="ChartPartWP" 
              List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp" 
              Path="ChartPartWP" 
              RootWebOnly="True">
        <File Url="ChartPartWP.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
            <Property Name="Group" Value="ChartParts" />
        </File>
        <File Url="LockedChartPartWP.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
            <Property Name="Group" Value="ChartParts" />
        </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

### feature.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
  Id="47D62F5E-B0E0-4f93-BCD1-081CA794527C" Version="3.5.1.0"
  Title="TCBOE ChartPart"
  Description="Provides a Chart Web object to be used in Sharepoint 2007."
  AutoActivateInCentralAdmin="TRUE"
  Scope="Site">
    <ElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="ChartPartWP.xml" />
        <ElementFile Location="ChartPartWP.webpart" />
        <ElementFile Location="LockedChartPartWP.webpart"/>
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Would there be any receivers/handlers i need make are implemented for the installation to take hold?  I didnt read anything about it but read something about a FeatureReceiver for a purpose, but cant remember for the life-of-it, why you need the FeatureReceiver ([SPFeatureReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeaturereceiver.aspx))

Comment: post your .ddf and manifest.xml the issue is most likly there somewhere...

Comment: What does your ChartPartWP.xml file look like?  The combination of your Path properties of the <Module><File></File></Module> elements might be messed up and not pointing to the proper location of your ChartPartWP.webpart file in the feature folder.

Comment: added the ChartPartWP.xml, feature.xml, and further analysis of the FeatureReceiver catch class that i implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SPFeatureDefinition.AutoActivateInCentralAdmin` [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfeaturedefinition.autoactivateincentraladmin%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Gets a value that specifies whether the Feature is activated on the central administrative Web site, site collection, or Web application upon installation.

Without testing your entire samples, using this property sounds off to me. Try removing that.

update: you should post your .webpart also (it is a xml).

Try these configs: Feature.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Id="47D62F5E-B0E0-4f93-BCD1-081CA794527C" Version="3.5.1.0" Title="TCBOE ChartPart" Description="Provides a Chart Web object to be used in Sharepoint 2007." Scope="Site">
    <ElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="ChartPartWP\ChartPartWP.xml" />
        <ElementFile Location="ChartPartWP\ChartPartWP.webpart" />
        <ElementFile Location="ChartPartWP\LockedChartPartWP.webpart"/>
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

webpart.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="ChartPartWP" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
        <File Path="ChartPartWP.webpart" Url="ChartPartWP.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
            <Property Name="Group" Value="ChartParts" />
        </File>
        <File Path="ChartPartWP.webpart" Url="LockedChartPartWP.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
            <Property Name="Group" Value="ChartParts" />
        </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

If nothing works, I would recommend installing and using the [VSeWSS 1.3 from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14154), create a new webpart, hit F5, test it. If you can see it in the "Add Web Parts" dialog, move your files over. This is the closest you will get to the SharePoint 2010 experience (which is terribly improved).

Having to fiddle with these files, even more to a beginner, should not be your burden.

Comment: ok, that got it to load up into CA....but when i goto activate it from the site(s) i get 'Failed to instantiate file "ChartPartWP.webpart" from module "ChartPartWP": Source path "ChartPartWP\ChartPartWP.webpart" not found. '

Comment: edited with a couple more suggestions, but I would recommend to go  with the Microsoft way to develop these little guys.

Comment: Well i am doing this against 2007 but not much of a difference from what i can tell on the development side.

Comment: As well in the feature.xml the stsadm doesnt like the folder structure prior to the location. Seems it uses the containing folder as the root.

Comment: Ok got it to work....why does `Path="ChartPartWP" RootWebOnly="True">` in **ChartPartWP.xml** cause problems with the site collection?

Comment: SharePoint has more obscure questions than answers, bugs, bad naming, inability to hide internal functionality in a configuration file, who knows? :)

Comment: Well from one frying pan to another.  Got it into the site but now i get this new freaking message....feel like the Xmas song with the guy about the lights ;)  New message: **A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.** could you point to the tentative location i should be looking?

Comment: going to post another question thread [SP 2007 - Webpart cannot be displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893145/sp-2007-webpart-cannot-be-displayed)