# SP 2007 - Webpart cannot be displayed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

Error: "A Webpart on this Page cannot be displayed or imported.  The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe"

Trying to find the details of this error in source-code but not quite sure where the exact problem is located.

refer to [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878798/sharepoint-2k7-custom-webpart-not-loading/7882656#7882656) for previous fixes performed.

Any pointers on a good location to start?

**DLL:** TCBOE.ChartPart.dll

**Namespace:** TCBOE.Chartpart

**FeatureReceiver.vb**

```
Private Shared Sub AddOrRemoveChartHandlerToWebConfig(ByVal web As SPWebApplication, ByVal remove As Boolean)
    Dim asm As String = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
      "System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version={0}, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken={1}", _
      New Object() {"3.5.0.0", "31bf3856ad364e35"})
    Dim modif As New SPWebConfigModification("add[@path='ChartImg.axd']", _
      "configuration/system.web/httpHandlers")
    modif.Owner = "TCBOE.ChartPart"
    modif.Sequence = 0
    modif.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode

    modif.Value = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
      "<add verb=""{0}"" path=""{1}"" type=""{2}"" validate=""{3}"" />", _
      New Object() {"GET,HEAD,POST", "ChartImg.axd", asm, "false"})
    If (remove) Then
        web.WebConfigModifications.Remove(modif)
    Else
        web.WebConfigModifications.Add(modif)
    End If

End Sub
Private Shared Sub AddOrRemoveChartSettingsToWebConfig(ByVal web As SPWebApplication, ByVal remove As Boolean)
    Dim appSettings As New SPWebConfigModification("appSettings", "configuration")
    appSettings.Owner = "TCBOE.ChartPart"
    appSettings.Sequence = 0
    web.WebConfigModifications.Add(appSettings)

    Dim keyVal As String = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
     "storage={0};timeout={1};", _
     New Object() {"memory", "20"})
    Dim modif As New SPWebConfigModification("add[@key='ChartImageHandler']", "configuration/appSettings")
    modif.Owner = "TCBOE.ChartPart"
    modif.Sequence = 1
    modif.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode

    modif.Value = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
      "<add key=""{0}"" value=""{1}"" />", _
      New Object() {"ChartImageHandler", keyVal})
    If remove Then
        web.WebConfigModifications.Remove(modif)
    Else
        web.WebConfigModifications.Add(modif)
    End If
End Sub
<SharePointPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, ObjectModel:=True)> _
Public Overrides Sub FeatureActivated(ByVal properties As Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureReceiverProperties)
    Dim site As SPSite = TryCast(properties.Feature.Parent, SPSite)
    Dim web As SPWebApplication = site.WebApplication
    AddOrRemoveChartSettingsToWebConfig(web, False)
    AddOrRemoveChartHandlerToWebConfig(web, False)
    web.Farm.Services.GetValue(Of SPWebService)().ApplyWebConfigModifications()
    web.Update()
End Sub
<SharePointPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, ObjectModel:=True)> _
Public Overrides Sub FeatureDeactivating(ByVal properties As Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureReceiverProperties)
    Dim site As SPSite = TryCast(properties.Feature.Parent, SPSite)
    Dim web As SPWebApplication = site.WebApplication
    AddOrRemoveChartSettingsToWebConfig(web, True)
    AddOrRemoveChartHandlerToWebConfig(web, True)
    web.Farm.Services.GetValue(Of SPWebService)().ApplyWebConfigModifications()
    web.Update()
End Sub
```

---

### Added: 10/26/2011 @ 11:36am

### Manifest.xml

(As created by WSPBuilder)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Solution created by WSPBuilder. 10/26/2011 8:19:40 AM  -->
<Solution SolutionId="ee03c5c2-c9bd-4cfe-ac16-225f8e28072b" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Assemblies>
    <Assembly Location="cablib.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
    <Assembly Location="TCBOE.ChartPart.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">
      <SafeControls>
        <SafeControl Assembly="TCBOE.ChartPart, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5" Namespace="TCBOE.ChartPart" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
      </SafeControls>
    </Assembly>
  </Assemblies>
  <TemplateFiles>
    <TemplateFile Location="IMAGES\ChartPartWP\oscillator_16.gif" />
    <TemplateFile Location="IMAGES\ChartPartWP\oscillator_32.gif" />
  </TemplateFiles>
  <FeatureManifests>
    <FeatureManifest Location="ChartPartWP\feature.xml" />
  </FeatureManifests>
</Solution>
```

Are there any situations where a CAS policy would restrict a local-machine user account (used to run services) would cause this kind of behaviour?

### Edit 11/3/2011:

Ok finally got a "Great Practices" install and it is stable and working.  Got the original control i am customizing to load and working as it should.

Went to go "install" my edited control and received this error response when trying to deploy the solution:

```
Feature '47d62f5e-b0e0-4f93-bcd1-081ca794527c' could not be installed because the loading of event receiver assembly "TCBOE.ChartPart, Verstion=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5" failed: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TCBOE.ChartPart, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
File name: 'TCBOE.ChartPart, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5' 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject() 

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. 
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. 
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. 
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: added featurereceiver code used in the control itself.

Comment: added error response from CA when trying to Deploy Solution

Comment: Found the problem was related to a botched install of the Sharepoint server.  Uninstalled and followed the install steps with a microscope and now it all works.

Answer (score 1):

The web part should be registered in web.config's SafeControls. It's very simple to do. Try the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms581321(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: can this be done automatically like through a FeatureReceiver?

Comment: @GoldBishop I wouldnt do it in a FeatureReceiver but in the manifest.xml file instead. Take a look at http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/UsingCodeBehindFilesInSharePointSites.aspx . You can also use WSPBuilder to dynamically generate the manifest. http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/ . I think it's important to do it the "hard" way first though to fully understand what all is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: i am all for doing it the LONG way first so when the SHORT version doesnt work then i have a fail safe.  Problem is that i downloaded the WSP of the original control and tried implementing it and i am getting the same result.  Is there a way of cleanly remove all components associated with the sight?  i think i have overimplementation bleed-over and notations are not getting removed when they are supposed to.

Comment: Ok, not quite sure why this error is occuring but found this in the Event Viewer: **Error initializing Safe control - Assembly:TCBOE.ChartPart, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5 TypeName: TCBOE.ChartPart.ChartPartWP Error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: Installed the MSChartControls for 3.5 and now i am getting the ImportErrorMessage from the .webpart element <importerrormessage> section.  Guess this leads me to find out what default values i have preset in there are not working with the datatype setup in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an usercontrol to render the webpart? If so, put this on the top of your UserControl:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
```

If you are not using an UserControl, just modify your code to add that line to your web.config inside the  tag:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

I told you this back in the other thread, you are doing the ultra-hard mode way trying to fiddle with this stuff by hand. If you were using SmartPart or VSeWSS 1.3 you would **not** go through all this.

Comment: True but you assume i am doing this from the code side of the page.  I am working on a webpart that is going to auto-place this information into the web.config when it is Activated, or remove itself if Deactivated.  Everything is being stated as if i would be the one doing this.  I am not the one, ultimately, that will be deploying/using this control.  So i am trying to make it as Admin-friendly as possible.  And i am only using aspects of the DataVisualization namespace to build and then render the graph.

Comment: This reusable redeployable magical wonder called Web Part has been done a billion times before yours and these "unexplainable" everyday requirements like using a unregistered dll from the BCL were never seen by mankind so the good practices don't apply, but I'm just assuming.

Comment: im under no dillusion that what i am having problem with are original by any means....its more of understanding if "this" then "that" else "do the other" and if all else fails "Delete *.*, Format C:, Reinstall" :)  Seriously, i am going to ask the same question from various angles, so you have to be patient.  I not unfamiliar with web-development just SharePoint deployment.  If this was a ASP.Net page, i would not be having these problems, but since i am using the SharePoint library framework, i am in personally uncharted territory.